# Issue with size of after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've a little problem with pseudo element `:after` on a link element.

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* line 1, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* line 3, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* line 7, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* line 9, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* line 16, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:hover,
.pagenav ul li a:focus,
.pagenav ul li a.active {
  color: darkgreen;
}
/* line 18, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:hover:after,
.pagenav ul li a:focus:after,
.pagenav ul li a.active:after {
  height: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
/* line 22, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:after {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 1px;
  background: darkgreen;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-8px);
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li class="pagenav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">No problem here</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">A text longer than the first is a problem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">No problem</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

As you can see, if a link is longer than the div, there is a line break but the pseudo element set is size from the beginning to the finish of the text.

I don't know why and I've already test to put a `display : block` to my link but it's not what i want because the size of the `:after` will not be "responsive" to the size of the link.

Comment: Don't know why this has been downvoted, it's clear problem with enough code to reproduce it in the question.

Comment: Maybe because i didn't say Hello, my bad

Comment: You get some miserable people on here who downvote anything and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem by making your link an `inline-block` element:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* line 1, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* line 3, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* line 7, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* line 9, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* line 16, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:hover,
.pagenav ul li a:focus,
.pagenav ul li a.active {
  color: darkgreen;
}
/* line 18, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:hover:after,
.pagenav ul li a:focus:after,
.pagenav ul li a.active:after {
  height: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
/* line 22, sass/partials/_sidebar.sass */

.pagenav ul li a:after {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 12.5%;
  right: 12.5%;
  height: 1px;
  background: darkgreen;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-8px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-8px);
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li class="pagenav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">No problem here</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">A text longer than the first is a problem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">No problem</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome :)  Please accept the answer if this is now resolved - click the tick below the voting arrows top left of the answer.